# Can I check how Haskell allocates memory?

Tags: haskell

Thanks to lazy evaluation, Haskell can process following expression in a moment.

```
head.head $ let m = 1000000000000000 in map (\n -> [m*n .. m*(n+1)]) [1 .. m]
```

But I noticed following expression doesn't finish, yet the memory usage stayed low.

```
last.last $ let m = 1000000000000000 in map (\n -> [m*n .. m*(n+1)]) [1 .. m]
```

It is not suprising that haskell can do that. But I wonder how it works. More precisely, how haskell allocate memory. Is there any way to check memory layout or something like that?

Comment: Read more on Haskell profiling: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_profile_a_Haskell_program . You can control memory usage in details.

Comment: The second code snippet does not consume a lot of memory, because it operates on lazy lists only with `map` and generators, cycling through it and requiring only one its item at a time. When previous items are not needed they're garbage collected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's simplify this example a bit to see what happens. You can mostly figure it out just thinking about lazy evaluation and graph reduction, without needing to go any lower-level than that. Let's look at a simplified reduction of `ourLast (mkList 3)` with this code:

```
ourLast :: [a] -> a
ourLast [] = error "ourLast []"
ourLast (x:[]) = x
ourLast (_:xs) = ourLast xs

mkList :: Int -> [Int]
mkList 0 = []
mkList n = let rest = mkList (n-1) in n : rest
```

`?foo` means "a value we haven't looked at yet". We create these with "let".
`foo@bar` means "a value we've already computed which we've figured out is `bar`"
    when we examine `?foo`, it becomes `foo@bar`
`foo := bar` means "we've not figured out that `foo` is `bar`"

```
    -- We start here by creating some value and giving it to ourLast to
    -- look at.
let ?list3 = mkList 3
ourLast ?list3
    -- At this point ourLast examines its argument to figure out whether
    -- it's of the form (_:_) or []
    -- mkList sees that 3 /= 0, so it can pick the second case, and it
    -- computes the value for ?list3.
    -- (I'll skip the arithmetic reductions and other boring things.)
    let ?list2 = mkList 2
    list3 := 3 : ?list2 -- we don't need to compute ?list2 yet, so
                        -- (mkList 3) is done and we can go back to ourLast
ourLast list3@(3 : ?list2)
    -- ourLast needs to examine ?list2 to find out whether it's [] or not,
    -- so mkList does the same thing again
    let ?list1 = mkList 1
    list2 := 2 : ?list1
ourLast list3@(3 : list2@(2 : ?list1))
    -- Now ourLast has enough information to continue;
    -- ourLast (_ : xs@(_ : _)) = ourLast xs
    -- Notice how we don't need to compute list2 a second time; we save its
    -- value the first time we compute it. This is what lazy evaluation is.
ourLast list2@(2 : ?list1)
    -- at this point, there are no references to `list3` anywhere, so it
    -- can be GCed.
    -- Repeat (ourLast examines ?list1, mkList sees that 1 /= 0).
    let ?list0 = mkList 0
    list1 := 1 : ?list0
ourLast list2@(2 : list1@(1 : ?list0))
ourLast list1@(1 : ?list0)
    -- Can GC list2.
    -- Now mkList is being called with 0, so it just returns an empty list.
    list0 := []
ourLast list1@(1 : list0@[])
1
    -- We're done! (And we can GC list1.)
```

Notice how at any given time we only need to have a couple thunks actually allocated, and the rest either aren't computed yet or can be GCed. When we evaluate `ourLast list3`, evaluation jumps back and forth between `ourLast` and `mkList` (sort of like coroutines).

If you want to get a more precise idea of how Haskell compilers tend to work, on the level of "when and how does allocation happend", the following are helpful:

- [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware: the Spineless Tagless G-machine](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.53.3729) (JFP paper)
- [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/index.htm) (online book)

A general understanding how lazy evaluation works just from the perspective of graph reduction -- e.g. [this article](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/lazy.xhtml) -- is useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would do some heap-profiling as explained [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html). For this you need to install the profiling libraries with cabal. The explanation is pretty comprehensive and easy to follow.